# How to know which type of kernel I'm running? (Monolithic or Microkernel)

Tags: kernel

From the `terminal` (command line console on linux or any microkernel based machine) can we identify which type of kernel is running?

Note:
I dont want to know the version or name of a kernel and search same on internet to find its type.

Comment: This is too broad... Given that you know the theoretical differences, you could instead identify some specific differences you’re interested in, and ask how to check them on the running kernel.

Comment: @StephenKitt e.g. Monolithic: User and Kernel services in same address space | Microkernel: User and Kernel services in different address space . . .How to check this difference on a running kernel?

Comment: AFAIK on Linux (which is monolithic) kernel space and user space use different address spaces :-/ (but please [edit] your question to make it more specific instead of adding comments).

Comment: @StephenKitt is it still too broad? please help :!

Answer (score 1):

Generally microkernels are only responsible for low-level stuff like IPC and context switches. There should not be any TCP/IP stack or Video drivers in kernel space with real micro-kernels.

But in real world such kernel would be too slow because of context switches. So some systems use hybrid kernels where may APIs sit on top of the microkernel.

- Linux: Monolithic kernel (everything including KMS and Netfilter work in kernel space either compiled into kernel or loaded as module)
- Windows: Hybrid. Microkernel + Executive (I/O, PnP, GDI etc) + Drivers + HAL.
- XNU: (Darwin: macOS / iOS): Hybrid. Microkernel called Mach (lower level) + BSD (upper level) + I/O kit for drivers.

Comment: We wont get the Kernel type (Microkernel / Monolithic / Hybrid or ...) directly (from command-line), But there are few things which might help us to get the type. Like, exploring the filesystem : from where we can get the system's structure, how the drivers are installed, how user-space and kernel-space is divided etc. once you get to know about this key points + your previous experience + theory : will guide you to judge which type of kernel it is.